# Can't switch from Unity to Gnome using gear icon

Tags: unity, gnome, lightdm, ubuntu-gnome, gdm

I have recently installed `ubuntu-desktop/unity` and gnome on my machine. When login prompts, I click on gear icon to switch to gnome environment but what I get is a hanged screen;on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, system again chooses unity. here are the photos for more clarity:-

When login prompts:

[image]

When I click on the gear icon:

[image]

When I press enter, I get the same screen as that of first image.

I am using lighdm as the display manager and have tried configuring it. 
My purpose is to switch to `gnome-shell` and remove `unity/ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: A fix is to backup your home folder and reinstall Ubuntu. If anyone ever finds a better solution, do share it here!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem solved it by switching to gdm3 and then the gear icon worked `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` - this command allows you to switch to gdm3

I think easier and better than reinstallation:)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this too.  As it turns out, you can use this menu with keyboard navigation, even if it doesn't display visually.  Here's what to do:

1. Click into the password field.
2. Hit the tab key once, and see that the shell icon highlights:

[image]

3. Hit enter, and see that the menu vanishes (as pictured above)
4. Hit tab a few times to cycle through the available options (I hit tab twice to find the desired option, but your mileage may vary)
5. Hit enter to make your selection, and see that the correct shell now displays:

[image]